# Dell "Rescue Disk" image size questions

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-backup, rescue-disk

I used Dell's provided software for creating a "Rescue Disk" image to a 32GB USB stick for a few laptops and have backed these up using [imageUSB](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html).

**Questions**

1. What is the recommended way that can be done to shrink these down since they take up 32gb each?
2. Is there a better way to store these backups?
3. I noticed that windows provides a mechanism for creating recovery drives. Would this solution be suitable too and provide better results?

Comment: You can use entirely different software that is more optimized but the image created cannot be made smaller.

Comment: @Ramhound What software would you suggest?